# How can i enable navigation bar only in IOS and disable the navigation bar in Android at the same time?

Tags: xamarin

I have disabled the navigation bar and i want to enable the bar only for ios and not for android.

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
```

I have done the disabling through this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a runtime `switch` on Device.RuntimePlatform:

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.Android:
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.runtimeplatform?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
#if __ANDROID__
   NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = false;
#endif
```

Comment: This will work only on a shared project. When using .NetStandard Device.RuntimePlatform is the way to go

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba i assumed that's what he was referring to. But I guess I should have included that in the answer